# Can I use @lombok.Getter in Kotlin for an Enum class constructor parameter?

Tags: class, kotlin, enums, getter, lombok

I am trying to add a @Getter to a parameter of an enum class constructor in a Kotlin enum class.

I've attempted this with the following code:

```
@Getter enum class Person(formattedName: String, startLoc: WorldPoint, endLoc: WorldPoint, levelRequirement: Int) {

DAVID("David", WorldPoint(39, 11, 0), WorldPoint(39, 39, 0), 5)
```

}

What I am trying to achieve is being able to access the parameters from a reference to an enum value in another class, as a @Getter would normally allow in Java.

```
Person person = Person.ordinal
println(person.getFormattedName())
```

Is this possible with lombok? Or must I go with the traditional method?

Comment: just use a kolin `val`:enum class Person(val formattedName: String,val startLoc: WorldPoint, endLoc: WorldPoint, levelRequirement: Int) {}

Comment: I see, so I don't even need to access it with a Getter. Thank you.

Comment: 1) Getter generation by lombok does not work in kotlin. 2) Declaring the parameters inside a constructor with `val` or `var` will generate getter/setter automatically since those become fields.